# Regex to extract multiple substrings from strings with a predictable format

Tags: php, regex, string

I got this string below.

```
string(49) "02/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = /86= | Weight: 50.00%"
string(49) "02/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = 50.83/86= | Weight: 50.00%""
```

The first example don't show any number before the `/`, in this case I need to use `00.00` as the default value.

I need to get this information and put in an array like this one:

```
$dados[ "date" ] = "02/12/2018"
$dados[ "markOK" ] = "50"
$dados[ "markTotal" ] = "86"
$dados[ "weight" ] = "50.00"
```

Other examples:

```
string(49) "02/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = /86= | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "06/11/2018 (Assessment 2) = 22.40/35=32.00 | Weight: 50.00%"
string(49) "04/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = /60= | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "11/09/2018 (Assessment 2) = 27.00/40=33.75 | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "09/09/2018 (Assessment 2) = 30.00/30=50.00 | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "14/08/2018 (Assessment 2) = 31.00/40=38.75 | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "19/06/2018 (Assessment 2) = 63.00/72=43.75 | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "17/06/2018 (Assessment 2) = 45.00/45=50.00 | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "22/05/2018 (Assessment 2) = 11.00/55=10.00 | Weight: 50.00%"
```

Comment: Even if unversed with regex, you should be able to make a description of how you intend to extract the string parts. Such as ➊ first a mix of numbers+forward slashes, ➋ then find the first `=`, ➌ get numbers before period or forward slash, ➍ the number directly after the slash, ➎ and the numeric part after the literal `Weight:␣`. Once you put it in words like that, a regex usually writes itself.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
(?P<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})[^=]+=\s(?P<markOK>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\/(?P<markTotal>\d+)[^:]+:\s(?P<weight>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

[Test online](https://regex101.com/r/JAudwM/2)

It's actually pretty simple.

- `(?P<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})` capture the date
- `[^=]+=\s` skip everything not an equal then the equal and a space
- `(?P<markOK>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?` capture float (optional)
- `\/` the slash
- `(?P<markTotal>\d+)` capture integer
- `[^:]+:\s` skip everything not a colon then the colon and a space
- `(?P<weight>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` capture float

**Update**

```
$pattern = '/(?P<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})[^=]+=\s(?P<markOK>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\/(?P<markTotal>\d+)[^:]+:\s(?P<weight>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)){
   var_export($matches);
}
```

If you want to clean up the matches array you can do it like this:

```
$str = '04/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = /60= | Weight: 50.00%';
$pattern = '/(?P<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})[^=]+=\s(?P<markOK>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\/(?P<markTotal>\d+)[^:]+:\s(?P<weight>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)){
    $default = [
        'date' => '00/00/0000',
        'markOK' => '0.00',
        'markTotal' => '0',
        'weight' => '0.00'
    ];

    $matches = array_filter($matches);
    $matches = array_merge($default, array_intersect_key($matches, $default));


   var_export($matches);
}
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c02298372d67f0db9d04234f7c93c7d151dade9f)

Output

```
array (
  'date' => '04/12/2018',
  'markOK' => '0.00',
  'markTotal' => '60',
  'weight' => '50.00',
)
```

Comment: It's work in online site...
but in the code dosen't work...

$result = preg_match_all( "/(?P<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})[^=]+=\s(?P<markOK>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\/(?P<markTotal>\d+)[^:]+:\s(?P<weight>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/", $contentInfo );

var_dump( $result ) . "\n";

Comment: preg match returns a boolean value, try using the 3rd argument for the matches,  see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: It's work perfect now :)
Have any change when the "markOk" is empty, replace for 00.00

Answer (score 0):

While using named capture groups certainly has purpose for this case, I find the syntax makes the pattern unnecessarily bloated and harder to read.  After matching the substrings (notably the optional 2nd substring), you'll need to write a condition to replace the zero-length string with `00.00`.

Here's what I recommend:

Code: ([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/9oYmj)) ([Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6BRVFw/1))

```
$strings = [
    "02/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = /86= | Weight: 50.00%",
    "06/11/2018 (Assessment 2) = 22.40/35=32.00 | Weight: 50.00%",
    "04/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = /60= | Weight: 50.00%",
    "11/09/2018 (Assessment 2) = 27.00/40=33.75 | Weight: 50.00%",
    "09/09/2018 (Assessment 2) = 30.00/30=50.00 | Weight: 50.00%",
    "14/08/2018 (Assessment 2) = 31.00/40=38.75 | Weight: 50.00%",
    "19/06/2018 (Assessment 2) = 63.00/72=43.75 | Weight: 50.00%",
    "17/06/2018 (Assessment 2) = 45.00/45=50.00 | Weight: 50.00%",
    "22/05/2018 (Assessment 2) = 11.00/55=10.00 | Weight: 50.00%"
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if (!preg_match('~(\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})[^=]+= (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?/(\d+)[^:]+: (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)~', $string, $m)) {
        echo "No match for string: $string\n";
    } else {
        $results[] = ['date' => $m[1], 'markOK' => strlen($m[2]) ? $m[2] : '00.00', 'markTotal' => $m[3], 'weight' => $m[4]];
    }
}
var_export($results);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'date' => '02/12/2018',
    'markOK' => '00.00',
    'markTotal' => '86',
    'weight' => '50.00',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'date' => '06/11/2018',
    'markOK' => '22.40',
    'markTotal' => '35',
    'weight' => '50.00',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'date' => '04/12/2018',
    'markOK' => '00.00',
    'markTotal' => '60',
    'weight' => '50.00',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'date' => '11/09/2018',
    'markOK' => '27.00',
    'markTotal' => '40',
    'weight' => '50.00',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'date' => '09/09/2018',
    'markOK' => '30.00',
    'markTotal' => '30',
    'weight' => '50.00',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'date' => '14/08/2018',
    'markOK' => '31.00',
    'markTotal' => '40',
    'weight' => '50.00',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'date' => '19/06/2018',
    'markOK' => '63.00',
    'markTotal' => '72',
    'weight' => '50.00',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'date' => '17/06/2018',
    'markOK' => '45.00',
    'markTotal' => '45',
    'weight' => '50.00',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'date' => '22/05/2018',
    'markOK' => '11.00',
    'markTotal' => '55',
    'weight' => '50.00',
  ),
)
```